# Count distinct column case when/conditional

Tags: postgresql, count, conditional-statements, distinct

I'm trying to count the distinct number of ids in a column and this works fine.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT messages.id) AS link_created
```

But when I try to count with a conditional, I get a syntax error, what's the proper syntax to add a case when or some other condition to only count the distinct message ids where the messages.link_label is present?

```
COUNT(DISTINCT messages.id CASE WHEN messages.link_label IS NOT NULL 1 END) AS link_created
```

My full query looks like this.

```
@customers = Customer.select("customers.*,
                                  COUNT(DISTINCT recipient_lists.id) messages_sent,
                                  COUNT(DISTINCT messages.id CASE WHEN messages.link_label IS NOT NULL 1 END) AS link_created,
                                  COALESCE(SUM(video_activities.video_watched_count),0) AS watched_count,
                                  COALESCE(SUM(video_activities.response_count),0) AS response_count,
                                  COALESCE(SUM(video_activities.email_opened_count),0) AS email_opened_count,
                                  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN video_activities.video_watched_at IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS unique_watches,
                                  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN video_activities.email_opened_at IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS unique_opens,
                                  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN video_activities.response_count > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS unique_responses,
                                  customers.updated_at AS last_login,
                                  SUBSTRING( email from POSITION( '@' in email) + 1 for length(email)) AS company")
                          .joins("LEFT JOIN messages ON customers.id = messages.customer_id
                                  LEFT JOIN recipient_lists ON messages.id = recipient_lists.message_id AND messages.link_label is NULL               
                                  LEFT JOIN video_activities ON messages.id = video_activities.message_id")
                          .group("customers.id")
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
    WHEN messages.link_label IS NOT NULL
    THEN messages.id
    ELSE NULL END)
AS link_created
```

Comment: You are very welcome!  I will add, for others visiting, the brief explanation that the Case statement result expressions needed to be given as either the thing to count as distinct (messages.id) or nothing to count (NULL).